# php count radio values

Tags: php, radio-button

I got a list of 20 questions with A or B answer, and for the result I need to count certain answers together to get a score, and its A and B mixed.

```
Question 1 <input type="radio" name="1" value="A" /> 
           <input type="radio" name="1" value="B" />
Question 2 <input type="radio" name="2" value="A" /> 
           <input type="radio" name="2" value="B" />
Question 3 <input type="radio" name="3" value="A" /> 
           <input type="radio" name="3" value="B" />

$result1 = $1A + $2B + $4A + $7B etc (count total of these answers)
$result2 = $3B + $5B + $6B etc
```

the results should be numeric, with checkboxes it would be easy because of unique names so values can be 1, but with radios I don't know how other then a lot of 'if 1=B then $var++', but i'm sure there is an easier way.

Comment: The name attribute shuld be text not a number. Set values to 0 or 1 respectively and count. Use arrays for name like name="answers[]"... google will give you more examples

Comment: You can use `name="some_name[]"` for all of your questions you want to get together. The `[]` makes it that php receives an array named `some_name` with the amount of selected radios with this name. So then you can simply use `count ($_GET['some_name'])` to get a numeric value.

Comment: with name="some_name[]" I can count the total, but I need not all A or B answers, but 1A+4B+5B+7A etc, i need to be able to count specific question results together.

Comment: and with all radiobuttons being some_name[] you can only select 1 answer for all questions, instead of 1 answer per question. Its not as easy as it seems :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);

  /*
  @param array $userInput - just the $_POST
  @param array $expected must be in format : [
    [1,'A'], 
    [2,'B']
    ]
  @return int
  */
  function countExpectedAnswers(array $userInput, array $expected) /*: int*/{
    $result = 0;
    foreach($expected as $ex){
        if(isset ($userInput[$ex[0]]) && $userInput[$ex[0]] === $ex[1]){
            $result ++;
        }
    }
    return $result;
  }

  $expectedAnswers = [
    [1,'A'],
    [2,'A'],
    [3,'B']
  ];

  echo 'Answered correctly: ' . countExpectedAnswers($_POST,$expectedAnswers);
  ?>

  <form method = 'post'>
    <div>
    Question 1 <input type="radio" name="1" value="A" > 
               <input type="radio" name="1" value="B" >
    </div>        

    <div>
    Question 2 <input type="radio" name="2" value="A" > 
               <input type="radio" name="2" value="B" >
    </div>         

    <div>
    Question 3 <input type="radio" name="3" value="A" > 
               <input type="radio" name="3" value="B" >

    </div>


    <input type = 'submit' value = 'go'>
  </form>
```